# sorting of expression with complex parts

Tags: output-formatting

I have an expression:

```
a + i*b + d + i*e + r = 0
```

Now I want *Mathematica* to sort this like:

> ```
> a + d + r + i(b + e)
> ```

How can I do that?

Comment: Is `i` meant to be an imaginary unit?

Comment: So you need `I` and to use `==` not `=` first of all.

Comment: Thanks, but it should not be a mathematica input, only to demonstrate the problem :D

Comment: Well, it does matter since you want some kind of MMa script, `I` and `i` behaves differently. Is this waht you are after?: `expr = a + I*b + d - I*e + r; Row[(ComplexExpand[{1, I} Through[{Re, Im}[expr]]]), "+"]` or more safe but with additional brackets `HoldForm[+##] & @@ (ComplexExpand[{1, I} Through[{Re, Im}[expr]]])`

Comment: Yep, that's right! I thought already about the command 'ComplexExpand', sometimes it does the right thing.

Comment: Sorry, read your comment after writing mine. 
I will try this :) Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure of your level of *Mathematica* experience, or the context of your need.  Some basic facts about *Mathematica* may be helpful.

1. *Mathematica* sorts output lexicographically (roughly alphabetic order). So if you have a choice of variable names make all of the complex coefficients later in the alphabet than the real coefficients. e.g.

   ```
   ComplexExpand[a + r I + b + s I + d]
   ```

   > ```
   >  a + b + d + I (r + s).
   > ```
2. *Mathematica* assumes that unassigned variables are in general complex numbers. `ComplexExpand[]` overrides this assumption.  You can also do it manually with something like: `Simplify[Re[exp], Assumptions -> {Element[{a, b, c, d, e, f}, Reals]}]`, which will give the real part of the expression, assuming the listed coefficients are Real.

I hope that you find this helpful.